# Identifying the nonlinear parabolic PDE $u_t = (u^2)_{xx}$.

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, differential-equations

A friend of mine in the department needs to know if the following PDE has been extensively studied
$$ u_t = (u^2)_{xx}$$
Or more generally, replacing the square by any function of $u$. One would like to know uniqueness and existence of its solution, and smoothness property, for example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since $(u^2)_{xx} = (2uu_x)_x$ this is (up to a rescaling) the [porous medium equation](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PorousMediumEquation.html) for $m=1$.

Comment: See also http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_non-linear_partial_differential_equations for questions of the form "is this a well-known PDE"?

Comment: And for the PME, see http://books.google.com/books?id=4E2Gc67b-dYC