# Does this PDE has a general solution?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes

$$K\frac{\partial }{{\partial x}}(h\frac{{\partial h}}{{\partial x}}) = \mu \frac{{\partial h}}{{\partial t}}$$
K and u are constants.
If no,how to get a asymptotic solution?ie,linearize

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/25431/identifying-the-nonlinear-parabolic-pde-u-t-u2-xx

Answer (score 2):

We may assume WLOG that $K=1$.  One family of solutions is $$h(x,t) = \frac{v(x)}{a+bt}$$ for arbitrary constants $a,b$, where 
$v(x)$ is a solution of the ordinary differential equation  $$v v'' + (v')^2 + a \mu v = 0$$

Another family of solutions is
$$h(x,t) = a \left(W\left(b e^{(x+ct) \mu c/a}\right)+1\right)$$
for arbitrary constants $a,b,c$, where $W$ is the Lambert W function.

Comment: "We may assume WLOG that $\: K=1 \:$" $\;\;$ except when $\: K=0 \:$. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: OK, but the case $K=0$ is left as an exercise.